# Terminology question: && operator

Tags: c#, operators, boolean

Well I have been reading quite a lot sources but they differ in definiton:

- && is logical operator of logical
  conjunction //I guess this is correct
- && is operator of logical AND //I
  think this is not precise from
  technical point of view
- && is
  conditional operator performing
  logical AND //I think this is right
  as well

While all are correct in terms of understanding, I would say the first one is most precise. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I've also seen "short-circuit AND", for languages where `&&` won't evaluate its right-hand-side if the left-hand-side was false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, Java, C++, C, and probably several other languages, `&&` is a programming language implementation of the boolean AND operator. It is designed to account for the following facts (that do not apply in pure propositional logic):

- Evaluating an operand may be computationally expensive
- Evaluating an operand may fail with an exception
- Evaluating an operand may enter an infinite loop

So a boolean expression in a programming language really has four possible outcomes: `true`, `false`, "exception", and "infinite loop". In some situations, one has two boolean expressions where the possible success of the second expression can be determined by looking at the first expression. For instance, with the expressions `foo != null` and `foo.bar == 42`, we can be certain that if the first expression is false, then the second expression will fail. Hence, the `&&` operator is designed to be "short-cirquited": If the left operand evaluates to false, the right operand is not evaluated. In all cases where both operands would evaluate successfully to true or false, this rule produces the same result as if one actually had evaluated both operands, but it allows for increased performance (because the right operand might not need to be evaluated at all) and increased compactness without sacrificing safety (if one takes care to structure the expression such that the left operand "guards" the right one). Similarly, `||` will not evaluate the right operand if the left operand evaluates to true.

A shorter answer is that although `&&` is strongly inspired by AND, it is designed to take certain programming peculiarities into account, and `a && b` should perhaps rather be phrased as "an expression that returns false if `a` is false, and the value of `b` if `a` is true".

Answer (score 1):

**The easy answer.**

It performs an AND operation on 2 logical expressions returnting a Boolean. It does not evaluate the second if the first is false.

To evaluate both regardless use &.

**The complicated answer.**

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm heading 12.3.3.23 seems most relavent.

I find myself unqualified to criticise the definition within.

> 12.3.3.23 && expressions
>
> For an expression expr of the form `expr-first && expr-second`:
>
> • The definite assignment state of v before `expr-first` is the same as the definite assignment state of v before expr.
>
> • The definite assignment state of v before `expr-second` is definitely assigned if the state of v after `exprfirst` is either definitely assigned or “definitely assigned after true expression”. Otherwise, it is notdefinitely assigned.
>
> • The definite assignment state of v after expr is determined by:
>
> > o If the state of v after `expr-first` is definitely assigned, then the state of v after expr is definitely assigned.
> >
> > o Otherwise, if the state of v after `expr-second` is definitely assigned, and the state of v after `expr-first` is “definitely assigned after false expression”, then the state of v after expr is definitely assigned.
> >
> > o Otherwise, if the state of v after `expr-second` is definitely assigned or “definitely assigned after true expression”, then the state of v after expr is “definitely assigned after true expression”.
> >
> > o Otherwise, if the state of v after expr-first is “definitely assigned after false expression”, and the state of v after expr-second is “definitely assigned after false expression”, then the state of v after expr is “definitely assigned after false expression”.
> >
> > o Otherwise, the state of v after expr is not definitely assigned.

[Example: In the following code

```
class A
{
    static void F(int x, int y) {
    int i;
    if (x >= 0 && (i = y) >= 0) {
       // i definitely assigned
    }
    else {
        // i not definitely assigned
    }
        // i not definitely assigned
    }
}
```

> the variable `i` is considered definitely assigned in one of the embedded statements of an if statement but not in the other. In the `if` statement in method F, the variable `i` is definitely assigned in the first embedded statement because execution of the expression (`i = y`) always precedes execution of this embedded statement. In contrast, the variable i is not definitely assigned in the second embedded statement, since `x >= 0` might have tested false, resulting in the variable `i`’s being unassigned. end example]

I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

Conjunction is another word for "and". So they're all correct in terms of their output.

In terms of how they actually *give* the output, `&&` usually doesn't evaluate the second argument if the first one is false.

Comment: `usually`? Isn't this defined in the C# standard?

Comment: @jgauffin: I meant "usually" as in "in most languages".

Comment: the question is tagged with `c#`.

Comment: @jgauffin: I did realize that, but you might notice that other answers and comments talk about other languages as well.

Comment: Yes. But they got lower rep and I therefore got higher expectations on you ;)

Comment: @jgauffin: o____o who said talking about other languages was bad in the first place?

Comment: Well. For starters you are not very clear on that you are speaking about the operator in general. Someone expecting a C# answer and reads your answer might faint or drop dead since it's not what they expected. They might just get sweaty hands if you are really lucky.